# How can a scrollable div and a fixed bottom div dynamically change height inside a wrapper?

Tags: css, scroll, height, overflow

I'm trying to stack 2 divs inside of a wrapper div. I need one div of a set height to stay at the **bottom** of the wrapper div, and I need the **top** div to scroll. I can't separate them because I want the wrapper to grow with content in the top div until it is too big for the screen and then start scrolling without hiding the bottom div.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/chongwaldo/ddpc2pk6/).

I can almost figure this out, however the **bottom** div overlaps the last bit of information in the **content** div. Is there a way to change the height of the **top** div such that it leaves room for the **bottom** div no matter it's height?

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="content">
      // Dynamically added information that
      // grows the height of div.content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    // Input box or static button panel
  </div>
</div>
```

### SCSS

```
.wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  .top {
    max-height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;

    .content {
      max-height: inherit;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
  }
  .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that hard.  Just need to use the calc feature:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddpc2pk6/5/)

You can keep the wrapper dynamic by setting the value in the variable, and then forego your `max-height: inherit` rules.

Here's the relevant **SCSS**

```
$box_height: 100vh;
.wrapper {
    height: $box_height;
    max-height: $box_height;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    .top {
        max-height: unquote("calc(" + $box_height + " - 150px)");
        overflow: hidden;
        
        .content {
            max-height: unquote("calc(" + $box_height + " - 150px)");
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `padding-bottom:150px` to the wrapper (150px is the height of the bottom div). Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddpc2pk6/1/). This will give enough space for the bottom div.

Comment: I would like to have the bottom div change sizes. If I was to add padding I would have to use jquery to dynamically change the padding value. Is there an easier way to stack the two divs?

Comment: How is the bottom div changing sizes? Is it different on each page depending on content, or does it change dynamically on the page? either way you will probably need user side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without adding padding or margin bottom to any of the div with content.
Here is code:

```
.wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;

  .top {
    padding-bottom:150px;
  }
  .bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
  }
}
```

you actually don't need the extra div ".content". The padding to div ".top" is the value equal to the height of the bottom fixed div. In case of dynamic height of bottom fixed div you need to change the padding value of top div using jQuery (no other alternative). But for the change in content dynamic, you don't need to add any jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified it a bit and got what I think you're going for:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top">
            // Dynamically added information that
            // grows the height of div.content
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            // Input box or static button panel
        </div>
   </div>
```

then for css:

```
    body{
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .wrapper {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .bottom {
        height:150px;
        width:100%;
        background: #f00;
    }
```

check out the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jakesezkoala/ddpc2pk6/3/)